# Can I reverse my Roth withdrawal AND put the money back exactly where it came from - my 2007 and 2008 Roth contributions?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira

I am 50 years-old.  Is there any way I can reverse a withdrawal from my Vanguard Roth account that I mistakenly initiated five days ago? I have MS and panicked while rereading the returns, seeing only line 12 (Business income) and not also line 7 (Wages), and thinking I had excess contributions for both years when in fact I did not.  Is a hardship waiver order to reverse the funds back into my Roth while also avoiding early withdrawal fees possible for me to obtain?

Thank you in advance!

I forgot to say that the excess Roth contributions (they weren't excess-that was my mistake) were from the years 2007 and 2008. Over the phone with Vanguard on 12/19/27 and thinking (mistakenly) that I had excess contributions for those years, I initiated the withdrawal of the "excess" funds (totaling $5161). Only after I got off the phone did I realize my mistake-that these funds were parts of legal, yearly contributions to my Roth account for those years. Can I now put these funds back into my Roth account as an indirect rollover?

Thank you! I really appreciate the advice.
Doug

Comment: You are unlikely to have early withdrawal penalties withdrawing if this is your first time withdrawing a small amount from Roth IRA, because contributions come out first when withdrawing from Roth IRA, and contributions can be withdrawn any time without any tax or penalty. Only if you have already withdrawn all contributions, and you are withdrawing earnings, would there be tax and penalty if you withdraw early.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the funds back into Roth IRA within 60 days and count it as an "indirect rollover" rather than a withdrawal. You can only do one indirect rollover each year.